# Usage of the word "submittal"

Tags: word-usage

It it appropriate to use the word *submittal* as follows?

> The report is ready for submittal.

Or, is it better to just say:

> The report is ready to be submitted.

Comment: Or - more commonly used in the UK, than *submittal* - *the report is ready for submission*. Any of the three are fine.

Comment: In my opinion, ready to be submitted is a better choice.  When you add "for..." I think "for" should only be followed by certain kinds of words.

Comment: Certainly, "to be submitted" is more common.  But "submittal" is used in certain business contexts, so use whatever is the usual terminology where you are.

Answer (score 2):

You could say, "The report is ready for [submission](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/submission)."

Answer (score 1):

"Submittal" is legitimate; although in dictionaries I just find it listed as a noun form related to "submit" (which it is), [BusinessDictionary.com](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/submittals.html) has several examples of "submittal" used in sentences.

Obviously the second version is also OK.

So grammatically, you're good either way.  I prefer the second one, because "submittal" is an unusual word.  "Keep it simple," as they say.

Comment: I agree.  I know we can all argue about the first option but no one will argue the second.

Answer (score 1):

Both *submittal* and *submission* (and *submitted*) refer to the act of putting something forward for consideration; so, both of your sentences are correct.

However, **submission** also (and less commonly) refers to the item that is being tendered, in which case:

- One may prepare his application for **submittal**.
- But one's application itself is called the **submission**.

Per *Oxford Dictionary...*

> **[Submittal:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/submittal)** the action or an act of submitting something or to something.
>
> **[Submission:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/submission)** a document presented for consideration or judgement.

Comment: @sumelic, it's apparent that my answer was flawed (thanks for pointing that out in such detail). I've made the corresponding changes, per your (implied) suggestions.

Comment: But the act of submitting is also *submission* (as well as *submittal*)

Comment: I mention that in my answer: *"Both submittal and submission (and submitted) refer to the act of putting something forward for consideration"*

Answer (score 0):

> The report is ready to submit.

Simple and direct.